# Python - calculating average polygon from array of points

Tags: python, arrays, average

In Python, what is the best way to average an array of points which represent multiple polygons?

The current code I have is:

```
 

    poly1 = [(2, 2), (10, 0), (10, 10), (2, 10)]
    poly2 = [(4, 4), (20, 0), (20, 20), (4, 20)]

    polys = []
    polys.append(poly1)
    polys.append(poly2)

    x1 = []
    x2 = []
    x3 = []
    x4 = []
    y1 = []
    y2 = []
    y3 = []
    y4 = []
    for poly in polys:   
        x1.append(poly[0][0])
        y1.append(poly[0][1])

        x2.append(poly[1][0])
        y2.append(poly[1][1])

        x3.append(poly[2][0])
        y3.append(poly[2][1])

        x4.append(poly[3][0])
        y4.append(poly[3][1])

    avg_x1 = np.average(np.array(x1))
    avg_y1 = np.average(np.array(y1))

    avg_x2 = np.average(np.array(x2))
    avg_y2 = np.average(np.array(y2))

    avg_x3 = np.average(np.array(x3))
    avg_y3 = np.average(np.array(y3))

    avg_x4 = np.average(np.array(x4))
    avg_y4 = np.average(np.array(y4))

    new_poly = [(avg_x1, avg_y1),(avg_x2, avg_y2),(avg_x3, avg_y3),(avg_x4, avg_y4)]
    print(new_poly)
```

This gives the correct answer,

`[(3.0, 3.0), (15.0, 0.0), (15.0, 15.0), (3.0, 15.0)]`

but there has to be a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: If the code is working you can ask on [codereview.se] (but read their help center before asking and cross-posting is not allowed)

Comment: Never realized the Code Review site was there. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With numpy: make use of numpy's vectorized `mean` and use map to covert back to list of tuples:

```
>>> list(map(tuple, np.mean(polys, axis=0)))
[(3.0, 3.0), (15.0, 0.0), (15.0, 15.0), (3.0, 15.0)]
```

Without numpy: use a nested list comprehension / generator expression:

```
>>> [tuple(sum(coord) / len(polys) for coord in zip(*points)) for points in zip(*polys)]
[(3.0, 3.0), (15.0, 0.0), (15.0, 15.0), (3.0, 15.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Elegant way using numpy

```
data = np.array([poly1, poly2])
[tuple(l) for l in np.average(data, axis=0)]
```

Output:

```
[(3.0, 3.0), (15.0, 0.0), (15.0, 15.0), (3.0, 15.0)]
```